# Subdomain redirect to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: apache, subdomain

I'm having this problem: when I access the URL "bobbabr.org", it's normal, but when I access the subdomain "ibobba.bobbabr.org", I'm redirected to "/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi".

I already try to delete the .htacess, re-create the subdomain and the folder, nothing worked.

I have two .htacess on the host: one in the root (/public_html) and other in the subdomain folder (/public_html/ibobba).

I don't know what to do. Any tips?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try clearing your cache. Sometimes the problem is browser-specific.